# how to access the drawable resources by name in android

Tags: android, drawable

In my application, I need to get the some bitmap drawables somewhere  where I do not want to keep the reference `R`. So I create a class `DrawableManager` to manage the drawables.

```
public class DrawableManager {
    private static Context context = null;

    public static void init(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public static Drawable getDrawable(String name) {
        return R.drawable.?
    }
}
```

Then I want to get the drawable by name somewhere like this( the car.png is put inside the res/drawables):

```
Drawable d= DrawableManager.getDrawable("car.png");
```

However as you can see, I can not access the resources by the name:

```
public static Drawable getDrawable(String name) {
    return R.drawable.?
}
```

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Note that your approach is almost always the wrong way to do things (better to pass the context into the object itself that is using the drawable than keeping a static `Context` somewhere).

Given that, if you want to do dynamic drawable loading, you can use [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
   context.getPackageName());
return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
```

Comment: `better to pass the context into the object itself that is using the drawable than keeping a static Context somewhere` Hi, can you tell me more?

Comment: @hguser - the reason you'd want a `Drawable` is to display it on the screen - every view/activity/fragment has a `Context` associated with it - pass that `Context` into your `getDrawable` method.

Comment: I somehow can't get this to work. My resource id ends up being 0 even when the drawable is available and I'm passing the right context.

Comment: @PratikMandrekar - Assuming you're attempting to get a resource such as `R.drawable.your_image`, you'd want to use `resource.getIdentifier("your_image", "drawable", context.getPackageName())` - without specific code it is hard to see what is wrong.

Comment: Note that your resource name should be without an extension at the end (at least for pictures), otherwise your resourceId will be 0. Do not pass "picture.jpg" as name, pass just "picture".

Comment: @MichaelAbyzov - that's correct for the same reason you don't write `R.drawable.picture.jpg` - no extensions exist for resources.

Answer (score 23):

You could do something like this.-

```
public static Drawable getDrawable(String name) {
    Context context = YourApplication.getContext();
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", YourApplication.getContext().getPackageName());
    return context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

In order to access the context from anywhere, you may extend Application class.-

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    private static YourApplication instance;

    public YourApplication() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And map it in your `Manifest` `application` tag

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApplication"
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you, I never know I can get the context this way before. It seems that it will make the codes cleaner.

Comment: Obtaining a `Context` in that manner, rather than passing it in, is bad for testability. For example, to test any method that calls `YourApplication.getContext()`, the test would have to instantiate `YouApplication` first in order for `YourApplication.getContext()` to not return null. Creating globals in the form of statics is general a bad practice.

Answer (score 9):

Modify image content:

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imagenElement);
    int resourceImage = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(element.getImageName(), "drawable", activity.getPackageName());
    image.setImageResource(resourceImage);
```

Answer (score 9):

Using Kotlin

```
fun Context.getResource(name:String): Drawable? {
    val resID = this.resources.getIdentifier(name , "drawable", this.packageName)
    return ActivityCompat.getDrawable(this,resID)
}
```

I wrote it as Extension function so It can be used at any place in code.

Note: `context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);` is **deprecated** in Java.

**Note**: name of file,is name without extensions for ex **"a.png"** name will be **"a"**.

Answer (score 3):

**You can achieve like this**

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("your_drawable_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

**Set *resourceId* In Imageview**

```
imageView.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answer adds anything that the others haven't? (Especially that given by [Raul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37305940/10871073)!)

Comment: Can this be called from within a class!?

Comment: Yes @Learn2Code

Answer (score 1):

if You need int resouce

```
 Resources resources = context.getResources();
 int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("eskb048", "drawable",context.getPackageName());
 // return like: R.drawable.eskb048.png
```

if your need Drawable 
   check the first answer is correct for all

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to create a map of your icons in your code

```
val iconMap: HashMap<String, Int>
```

String is your key (to that drawable resource) that you can keep in your database, or even the key from backend API response

Int is the resource drawable

```
iconMap.put("cat", R.drawable.ic_cat)
iconMap.getOrDefault("dog", R.drawable.empty)
```

This way you make resource usage more visible to other devs

Comment: Seems like you are just duplicating the functionality Android provides, all be it with a different data structure. This will just consume extra memory when it is not needed.

Comment: the memory impact is smaller than the impact of knowing where a resource is used

Comment: I do not see how holding extra strings, integers and related code, and the then extra method activation records this will require to use the HashMap, in memory is faster than getting those same integer values from R.java?

Comment: ```
    fun assetToDrawable(assetName: String): Int {
        val iconMap = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
        iconMap.put("cat", R.drawable.ic_cat)
        iconMap.put("you", R.drawable.ic_you)
        return iconMap.getOrDefault(assetName, R.drawable.empty)
    }
```
It's about the IDE visibility, for those who need it