# Android accessing drawable folder

Tags: android, image, drawable

I placed 10 images in drawable folder and I created a custom class which instances are holding an id Integer that should refer it to a image from draw folder. Now I wonder how to set those id-s at once, not one by one. Instead:

```
object[0].setImage(R.drawable.image1);
object[1].setImage(R.drawable.image2);
```

I want to do this with loop, but how?

Comment: I think there's no good method for this... I used `int[] array = new int[]{ R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, etc... };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't work as far as I think.

There is code to get a drawable by its name. For example: `"image"+myNumber"`

Maybe: [how to access the drawable resources by name in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

`Drawable` ids as known are generated within static classes of `final class R`. So just use reflection to read the values of these static attributes. If you want to get the Int ids then use this code:

```
    for(Field f : R.drawable.class.getDeclaredFields()){
        if(f.getType() == int.class){
            try {
                   int id = f.getInt(null);
                   // read the image from the id
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Or if you want to search directly by images' names, you might be interested of the name attribute of fields like :

```
    for(Field f : R.drawable.class.getDeclaredFields()){
        if(f.getType() == int.class){
            try {
                String name = f.getName();
                // rest of the code handling file loading
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the size of the view's list should match with the one that holds the ids:

```
public class HolderIDs {

public List<Integer> _ids;

public HolderIDs() {
    _ids = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.ldrawable.three, R.drawable.four));
}

public List<Integer> getIDs() {
    return _ids;
}

}
```

//Usage

```
List<ImageView> views = getYourViews();

List<Integer> ids = new HolderIDs().getIDs();

for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
    View view = views.get(i);
    if (view == null) return;
    int id = ids.get(i);
    view.setBackgroundResource(id);
}
```

Comment: It wont work for me cos i will have 100+ images. Is there any other place where i could place my images, and later to connect them to the right objects?

Comment: Use reflection, as @eldjon suggest to you.

Comment: 100 images will make your APK file very large. Perhaps you can serve them over the internet from some server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an integer array for the resources:

int resources = [ R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ...]

And use a bucle to set the resources into your object array.

Comment: how does that help if he has to write them manually one by one in the array?

Comment: So you can use the next code:

int elements = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
   Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier("resource_"+i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}

Comment: thats no help whatsoever. if he adds an image to the folder he would need to change the array again. the point of the question is to get the list of drawables without having to go one by one

Comment: Yes but if he need a filter it works maybe he wants some images with a format no the icon app and others.