# How to open a JPG file as a BITMAP stored on the .../res/drawable-hdpi/?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I want to open a JPG file as Bitmap that stored on `drawable-hdpi` folder.
But i do not use `R.drawable.filename` , because I don`t know its name. I only have a String of its name.

```
String IMAGE = String.valueof(Random());
```

In otherwise, I want to open an Image file with name IMAGE stored on the `.../res/drawable-hdpi/`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Bitmap by

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);
```

Comment: It is the name of your resource file that is jpg in your case

Comment: I don`t have name of file, I have a string of name.

Comment: check this on how to get the resource id from the name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android