# local image through json in android

Tags: java, android, json, imageview

SO i have json file which contain this code :

```
{
 "gejala": "Apakah hawar berwarna kuning terang menuju ujung daun",
 "gejala_kode": "GJL0025",
 "penyakit_kode": "PNY0012",
 "gambar_gejala":"hawar_daun",
 "child": null
}
```

hawar_daun is name of the image i put on my drawable folder.

my xml part :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/big_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="null"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:id="@+id/ask"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/gambargejala"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is part of my java code which i want to put the image.

```
public class KonsultasiBerdasarkanGejalaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String ASK_GEJALA = "Apakah terdapat tanda-tanda ini?" ;

int qIndex = 0;
int level = 0;
TextView header;
TextView ask;
ImageView askgambar;
Button ya;
Button tidak;
ScrollView lyContainer;


boolean calculate = false;
boolean fromTidak = false;
int calcCount = 0;
int yaCount = 0;
int tidakCount = 0;

boolean lastQuestion = false;
PohonKeputusan pohonKeputusan;

Padi padi;
String[] gejalaPadi;
ArrayList<PenyakitPadi> allPenyakit;
ArrayList<PenyakitPadi> relPenyakitPadiArr;
ArrayList<PohonKeputusan> pohonKeputusanObjArr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_konsultasi_start);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

    setTitle("  Menu Konsultasi");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("  Berdasarkan Gejala");

    lyContainer = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.lyContainer);

    Intent padiIntent  = getIntent();
    padi = padiIntent.getExtras().getParcelable("padiObj");
    gejalaPadi = padi.gejala;
    relPenyakitPadiArr = setRelatedPenyakit();
    try {
        pohonKeputusanObjArr = setRelatedGejala(initiatePohonKeputusan());
        Log.e("pohonKeputusanObjArr", String.valueOf(pohonKeputusanObjArr.size()));
        Log.e("pohonKeputusanObjArr", String.valueOf(pohonKeputusanObjArr.toString()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pohonKeputusan = pohonKeputusanObjArr.get(qIndex);
    //Log.e("pohonKeputusan", String.valueOf(pohonKeputusan.gejala_kode));

    String namaPadi = padi.nama;
    if (namaPadi != null) {
        namaPadi = namaPadi.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + namaPadi.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        String ni = header.getText().toString();
        ni = ni + "\"" + namaPadi + "\"";
        header.setText(ni);
    }

    ask = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ask);
    askgambar=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gambargejala);

}

public ArrayList<PohonKeputusan> setRelatedGejala(ArrayList<PohonKeputusan> phk){
    ArrayList<PohonKeputusan> phkObjArr = new ArrayList<PohonKeputusan>();
    for (int i = 0; i < phk.size(); i++){

        boolean result = false;
        PohonKeputusan phkObj = phk.get(i);
        String gejalaKode = phkObj.gejala_kode;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < gejalaPadi.length; i2++){
            if(gejalaKode.equals(gejalaPadi[i2])){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(result == true) phkObjArr.add(phkObj);
    }
    return phkObjArr;
}


public void rollbackQuestion(ArrayList<PohonKeputusan> phk){
    qIndex = 0;
    pohonKeputusan = phk.get(qIndex);
}

public void setQuestion(PohonKeputusan phk){


    ask.setText(phk.gejala);


    ------------------------------------??????????----------------------------
}
```

What code i must input in that last line on that last line to set the image from name file from json?

Thanks you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access the drawable resources by name in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to convert a String into a resource ID.
If that is the case, you can use [getResources().getIdentifier(name, type, package)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Here is an example.

```
public void setQuestion(PohonKeputusan phk){
    ask.setText(phk.gejala);
    askgambar.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(phk. gambar_gejala, "drawable", getPackageName()));
}
```

Comment: yes that exactly what i mean friend, thankkk uu so mucchhhhhh . :)