# I need a way to dynamically, programmatically change the background for a ImageView in a Recycler View

Tags: android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have a set of 200+ flag images. I want to dynamically select an flag image to match a country in a RecyclerView.

This code allows me to select a flag:

```
p0?.imageViewFlag?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.china)
```

How can I programmatically change the image reference?

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from calling it again? Or is your question how to avoid manually specifying the drawables for every image?

In this case, you'll typically add the image setting logic to an Adapter, and pass a list of all the image drawable resources for it to load. If you'd like to avoid creating a list of all the resources, you may consider avoiding proguard and searching the resources by name to match all drawables starting with "flag_". In that case, you'd be naming all of your flags like `flag_usa`, `flag_china` etc.

A relevant response for getting drawables resources by name can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android)