# Set image on a button where buttonname is coming from the database

Tags: android, string, image

In case I have to set an image on a button, programmatically, then I use the following code:

```
        Drawable img;
        ToggleButton tb_button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tglButton);
        img = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.p189, null );
        tb_button.setCompoundDrawables(img,null,null,null);
```

Now the situation is that I have read the name of the image from a database into a variable. Thus lets assume that my variable has the following value:

```
String img_str= "p189";
```

Now how do I set the same image on the button when the image name is stored inside a variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android

Answer (score 0):

use following method to get image from string.

```
 private int getImageFromString(String name) {
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
    return resId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create drawable resource id reference dynamically as follows

```
int resId=getResources().getIdentifier(img_str, "drawable", context.getPackageName())
img = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), resId, null )
```

and of course don't forget about try catch in case of wrong resource name

Answer (score 0):

You can get drawable as follows by itss name,

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

So elaborating on what [ABK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50409534/3625488) said. You can get the the [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable) ResId and then use that to get the drawable within a function like this:

```
private Drawable getDrawableFromString(String name) {
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
    return getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```