# Is there a way to use multiple sources for the same ImageView?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to use an Activity which displays a random object from my array. This object is passed in from an intent.

I am trying to use an image for each of these objects and then display the correct image for the correct object.

So far I've been using the drawable folder to hold my images and then loading them in through the XML however this stops me using multiple images for the same ImageView.
I tried using  imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename); but that doesn't seem to like loading in for some reason.
Do I need to make a new activity for each of the objects in this case?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_race);

    TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.raceName);
    Intent secondIntent = getIntent();
    Race message = (Race)secondIntent.getSerializableExtra("RACE");

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.raceImage);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hacan);
    image.setImageBitmap(imageToBitmapImage(message, image));

    name.setText(message.getName());
}
```

Bytes to Bitmap method

```
 public Bitmap imageToBitmapImage (Race message, ImageView image){
    Bitmap bmp;
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(message.getImageName());
        BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int input = buffer.read();

        while (input != -1){
            baos.write(input);
            input = buffer.read();
        }

        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        return bmp;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Class of each object I'm talking about.

```
public class Race implements Serializable {
private String name;
private String imageName; //name of file within drawable
```

Comment: You should choose between going with setImageResource or setImageBitmap. About your imageToBitmapImage function, your FileInputStream is going to read the data in your app folder on the phone, but that can't read the drawables you put in your project. Did you check you are not logging some exceptions there?

Comment: @XavierFalempin I checked now and it is giving a File not found. Where could I put these images so I can reference them? I'm still new to Android so apologies if this is a basic problem.

Comment: Svarr answer should work but you can also use the drawable id value as int in your pojo instead of the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @XavierFalempin commented, you can't access ressources through a file stream. Using `setImageResource()` should work. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369892/11084826) your `onCreate()` method should look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_race);

    TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.raceName);
    Intent secondIntent = getIntent();
    Race message = (Race)secondIntent.getSerializableExtra("RACE");

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.raceImage);
    image.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(message.getImageName(),
                                                        "drawable",
                                                        getPackageName()));

    name.setText(message.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Svarr, unfortunately that didn't solve the issue I'm having.

Comment: Then I misunderstood. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: I'm trying to display an image in an activity based on the "Race.getImageName" which is the filepath. I get the this from an Intent between 2 activities however I don't seem to be able to change the ImageView in the second activity based on the filepath I've been using. It could possibly be a Manifest or activity XML issue.

Comment: Can you give an example value for `getImageName()`? For my solution I expected it to be just the filename without extension (like `hacan` in your example).

Comment: Apologies I didn't realise it had to just be filename instead of with extension, I've changed it now and that works perfectly. Thank you!