# I want to use var to determine which photo to load into the image-view- Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-imageview

I have a `var` with kind of food in it (For example: pizza, burger ext.), I want to use that `var` to load a apecific image based on that `var` value from my `drawable` directory into the image view without using `when`.

I have those files: pizza.png, burger.png

I want to use something like this:

```
var food = "pizza.png"
food_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.food)//image is the pizza
food = "burger.png"
food_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.food)//image is the burger
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access the drawable resources by name in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android)

Comment: Use `map` to get a key/value pair with food name as key and drawable as value.

Comment: @Ivan yes I tried to find his but couldn't any way what I needed is the resourceId and only the answer down here did this.

Comment: the answer given below is just exactly the same as the one in the question I commented above.

Comment: I know but he gave me the correction I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can use following method:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("[your_drawable_name]", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
return resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
```

With this you can specify the name of your rawable and load it.
If you need only the resourceId you can return the resourceId without getting the drawable itself.

Comment: To set resource to an image I need it to be an Int, which one of these options returns the Int it's asking for?

Comment: It worked, I used only the resourceId, Thank you very much!

Comment: This is doomed to make typo's and crashes

Answer (score 2):

You could use an enum which corresponds to the right drawable for example

```
enum class FoodTypes(private val value: Int) {
    PIZZA(R.drawable.pizza),   
    BURGER(R.drawable.burger);

    fun getValue(): Int = value
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
var food = FoodTypes.PIZZA
food_icon.setImageResource(food.getValue())
food = FoodTypes.BURGER
food_icon.setImageResource(food.getValue())
```

Comment: I gave only two exmples, I have about 12 icons I want to switch between them

Comment: then you fill the enum with your 12 items.

Comment: The answer above is much more efficient to this matter I think

Comment: I Think the above code is doomed for typo's. I think in OOP perspective this is more clean and reusable

Answer (score 0):

why not doing this ?

```
var food = R.drawable.pizza
food_icon.setImageResource(food)//image is the pizza
food = R.drawable.burger
food_icon.setImageResource(food)//image is the burger
```

Comment: Because I gave only two exmples, I have about 12 icons I want to switch between them