# Is there a way to set the image from the drawable folder with my Json data, The data includes the name of the image in the drawable folder

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview, cardview

So far I have this without crashing.

```
String logoImage = JO.getString("logo");

            if (JO.getString("logo") == "able")
            {
                channel.ivLogoPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.able);
            }
```

The problem is, It's not changing the image.
I've tried the .setDrawable and that didn't work either.

```
            String logoImage = JO.getString("logo");

            if (JO.getString("logo") == "able")
            {
                //int drawable1 = R.drawable.abc;
                channel.ivLogoPic.setDrawable(R.drawable.able);
            }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369892/3111083. Just maintain the same name in database and drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Though [ @sunil sunny ] has already mentioned a helping link, I would also like to add some solution here that could be handy.
Remember, the efficiency of this solution, in cases like yours, will decrease with increasing number of drawable resources. Meaning, do this if there are not many drawables to use.

What you can do is first get the drawables as global variables in the recyclerview adapter:
`int drawable1 = R.drawable.drawable1, drawable2 = R.drawable.drawable2` ... etc.

Then inside `onBindViewHolder()` simply use the resources depending upon what is obtained from the JSON response.
Like:

```
if(logo == 1)
{
logoImageView.setDrawable(drawable1);
}
```

One advantage to note of this is you can change drawables easily, and not have to resort to changing names in both resource file as well as the API. Meaning, decouples the two. 
**PS: The codes written here are for reference only.**

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out in my backgroundTask.Java file I have

```
while (count<jsonArray.length())
        {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            count++;
            Channel channel = new Channel(JO.getString("name"),JO.getString("logo"));

            Channel logoImage = new Channel(JO.getString("logo"));

            if (logoImage.equals("axle"))
            {
                channel.ivLogoPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.axle);
```

Then I had to set the change in the Adapter

```
if(channel.getLogo().equals("axle")){
            holder.ivLogoPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.axle);
        }
```