# How do I access images dynamically while using 'setImageResource' in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set images in a recyclerView dynamically based on their name in the drawable resource file and their corresponding "image number" in the database (the number they're assigned in the database corresponds to the image they should use from the drawable resource file).

I've gotten this far but I'm stuck with using 'setImageResource(x)' where x is the image number.

The code below doesn't work, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        Item currentItem = items.get(position);
        String imgNo = "R.drawable." + String.valueOf(currentItem.getPicturenumber());
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(currentItem.getTitle());
        holder.textViewText.setText(currentItem.getText());
        holder.imageViewImage.setImageResource(imgNo);
    }
```

In the image below you can see I have three files named 1, 2 and 3. This number corresponds to the image number they're assigned in their database. I'm essentially trying to get the highlighted line to change based on what the currentItem's PictureNumber is.

[image: CodeScreenshot]

Comment: Instead of saving the image name in the db, save the image id (R.drawable.image). Then just get the id from the item holder and set it to imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but I recommend you store `resource id` (R.drawable.1) in `Item` instead of `int`

```
Resources resources = itemView.getContext().getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(String.valueOf(currentItem.getPicturenumber()), "drawable", 
   itemView.getContext().getPackageName());
holder.imageViewImage.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving the "drawable name" in database, you should try this :

```
private Context context;
```

```
onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
    // Required code here
    // then assign the context from here:
    context = parent.getContext();
    return vh;
}
```

Or You could do this to get the context

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    context = recyclerView.getContext();
}
```

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        Item currentItem = items.get(position);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(String.valueOf(currentItem.getPicturenumber()), "drawable", 
        context.getPackageName());
        holder.imageViewImage.setImageResource(resourceId);

    }
```

However, if you save the resourceId i.e R.drawable.your_drawable, then you can directly use

```
holder.imageViewImage.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369892/5617322 for more detail and understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed my items to have Picturename instead of Picturenumber.

I'm getting an 'Cannot resolve symbol itemView' error. Would this have something to do with my onCreateViewHolder method?

https://i.imgur.com/EGabu5E.png

Comment: Yes, you can be the context from onCreateViewHolder(). I have updated the answer, please have a look at it.