# How to check whether file exists in drawble folder

Tags: android

how to check whether a file exists in the drawable folder in runtime if yes how to access the file in runtime.

how to get the file from mipmap directory as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method

```
public static boolean isResource(Context context, int resId){
    if (context != null){
        try {
            return context.getResources().getResourceName(resId) != null;
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ignore) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

if you want to check by string name of drawable you can use,

```
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());

if ( checkExistence != 0 ) {  // the resource exists
    result = true;
}
else {  // checkExistence == 0  // the resource does NOT exist
    result = false;
}
```

Comment: i dont know the resource id , but I know the file name how to check with the use of file name@behrad

Comment: @Berryfarm check the code again, I edited it.

Comment: thanks behrad and one more doubt , I want set image source in runtime ,do we have any ways?@behrad

Comment: or in nutshell in your above program ..... if the file exits i want to retrieve the file is it possiblle@behrad

Comment: yes, you can. first, check that source exist by the above code, then use this code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369892/9474700 . also they are so similar you can mix them. and don't forget to vote for my answer :) @Berryfarm

Comment: but it doesn't point how to pick a value from the mipmap directory?@behrad

Comment: replace "mipmap" with "drawable".

Comment: Nope don't find any method regarding Mipmap@behrad

Comment: Resources resources = getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("ic_launcher_logo", "mipmap",
                getPackageName());

Answer (score 0):

**To check drawable folder image file exists:**

```
boolean isImgFileExists = isDrawableImageFileExists("ic_launcher");

private void isDrawableImageFileExists(String imgFileName){
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgFileName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    return id != 0;
}
```