# How to customize the src attribute of ImageView in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I want to write an app, which has a function like this: I put more than 800 photos in drawable in advance, numbered from a111 to a886, and then calculate an int type data according to the age, birthday and other information entered by the user, which exactly matches the number of the picture, so that it can be displayed in the next interface. But how do I write the src  attribute in ImageView, Please help me!!!!

Here is the XML file code I wrote：

```js
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_columnSpan="8"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a111"/>
```

The code of the result of the calculation and processing of the information passed in the first interface in Java file is as follows:

```js
int qigua=shanggua*100+xiagua*10+dongyao;
```

"qigua" is the final result,so The number of the image to be displayed is: a + qigua, but this can't be written directly in src，So I'm thinking about how to transfer the qigua calculated in Java to the XML file as the number of the image and write it to src, or what other methods are there.

Comment: imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a111));
In activity where you will use it.

Comment: getDrawable() is deprecated so the method is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set image in your image view using one of the following method in your activity class.

```java
myImgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a111);
```

You can use also :

```java
myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a111);
```

You can change the resource drawable according to the age in your program.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have a small question. As shown in the code of two files in my question, the method you gave should be written in a java file, but the most important problem is that the picture is not necessarily determined by "a111" or "a112", which is not a specified change, but is determined by the calculated int variable qigua, I can't write R.drawable.qigua for the method you gave me, so this method is still not good，so i want to know how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create the required drawable id as a **String** using your calculations, and then use the generated id to get your resource file. Here is an example of how this might work

```
//Creating id for image
fun getStringResourceId(): String {
    //Perform your calculations
    var id: String = "a123"
    return id
}

//Fetch resource id from the string id
fun convertStringToResourceId(stringId: String): Int {
    return context.resources.getIdentifier(stringId, "drawable", context.packageName)
}

//Use the resource id in your ImageView
fun setUserImage(resourceId: Int) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resourceId)
}
```

For more information, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android)

EDIT: @richard This is how you can set the image

First, you call `getStringResourceId()`. This method will give you your `qigua` value. Let's say it returns a value of `a111`.

Second, you pass this value of `a111` to the method `convertStringToResourceId(a111)`. What this will do is return an integer resource id for the resource present at `R.drawable.a111.jpg`.

Last, you pass this integer resource id to the `setUserImage(resourceId)` method and it will set that drawable to the imageView that you have.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the java file, I have got the int result ：qigua ，and the image name of string type ：Source = a + qigua. so i want ask：Do you need to write the setuserimage function to the java file?

Comment: The setUserImage method should be in your activity or fragment (whichever you are using to show the image)

Comment: So basically the first method is your business logic, you can place it where you deem best. The other two methods would typically be in your activity or fragment or in a class which has access to the context.

Comment: Hello, senior, I still don't know how to use“” imageview.setimageresource (resourceid) “”to display pictures. I have added the codes of my two files above. One is the ImageView setting in XML file, and the other is the int value "qigua" obtained by calculation in java file, The file name of the image to be displayed is "a" + "qigua" + ". JPG" in drawable. For example, if qigua = 111, the image to be displayed is "a111.jpg". Is it realized by the method you gave?