# How to call one of multiple animations in raw directory

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lottie

I'm trying to use a random number generator to pick between one of 10 different animations to run using a Lottie implementation. I've named the animations animation1 to animation10. When directly inputing one of the animations like this there's no issue:

```
animationView.setAnimation(R.raw.animation2);
```

but the app keeps on crashing when inputing it like this:

```
LottieAnimationView animationView = findViewById(R.id.animationViewer);
randNumber = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;

animationView.setAnimation("R.raw.animation" + randNumber);
```

With the cause being:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: R.raw.animation2
```

Comment: `setAnimation("R.raw.animation" + randNumber);` - setAnimation requires resourceId while you are passing a string value. Try [accessing drawable by it's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this to be the best solution

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
String animationDir = "animation" + randNumber;
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(animationDir, "raw", context.getPackageName());
context.getPackageName();

animationView.setAnimation(resourceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because `setAnimation()` requires a ResID and not a string.

Instead, you can use an `Array` like this

```
<integer-array name="animations">
    <item>@anim/animation1</item>
    <item>@anim/animation2</item>
</integer-array>
```

And then, you can use your random number.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to send a resource id as a string
you can create an array of resources or the easiest but not the cleanest way is :

```
 animID = when(randNumber){
```

1 -> {R.raw.animation1}
2 -> {R.raw.animation2}
.
.
.
.
10 -> {R.raw.animation10}
}

animationView.setAnimation(animID);